# Changing the Visual Composer CSS path to prevent https errors

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

My WordPress website (built by a sloppy contractor - they won't be able to fix it) has an absolute path to one of the CSS files. As a result, the visitors get warnings (and with some settings unable to load) when visiting the https pages.

Here is the fragment, the culprit is the last line:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gt3_theme-css'  href='https://mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/theme.css?ver=4.8.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gt3_custom-css'  href='https://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/custom.css?ver=4.8.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='AllFonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A400%2C300%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C500%2C700%2C900&#038;ver=4.8.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bsf-Defaults-css'  href='http://mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/smile_fonts/Defaults/Defaults.css?ver=4.8.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I tried looking through the manual code (PHP, other CSS files) but it's not there.

I tried googling "bsf-Defaults-css" and found references to WPBakery, but going to the plugins yielded no results.

Any idea where it came from and how I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the way.

Looks like it was coming from the default path to the WordPress installation. To fix it, modify the WordPress *Settings*, specifically `WordPress Address (URL)` with the https prefix. No need to modify the website address.

It's dumb but it works.